# printing "!" in the missing letter in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that takes `partial_alphabetic` and a string.

This function should take each character in the string and find its i-th position in `partial_alphabetic` and get the corresponding character in the known alphabetic (a,b, c, etc.) and if the character is unkown it should print "!" in its place.

Here is my code:

```
def cipher_attack(partial_alphabetic,ciphertext):
    var = ""
    for i in xrange(len(ciphertext)):
        letter = ciphertext[i]
        for j in xrange(len(partial_alphabetic)):
            if(partial_alphabetic[j] == letter):
                c = partial_alphabetic.index(letter)
                var += alphabet[c%26]
        var += "!"                    
    print var


cipher_attack("!wertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm","rqr")
```

It prints `d!!d!` but it should print `d!d` instead.

Comment: you always append `!`. what did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be improved like this

```
def cipher_attack(partial_alphabetic,ciphertext):
    var = ""
    for i in xrange(len(ciphertext)):
        if ciphertext[i] in partial_alphabetic:
            var += alphabet[partial_alphabetic.index(ciphertext[i]) % 26]
        else:
            var += "!"
    print var

cipher_attack("!wertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm","rqr")
```

**Output**

```
d!d
```

Comment: I'd suggest you change `for i in xrange(len(ciphertext)):` by a `for i, letter in enumerate ciphertext`. Or even `for letter in ciphertext` if you don't need the index.

Answer (score 1):

Break out of the `for` loop when you find a match, then give the loop an `else:` suite. That suite will only be executed when the loop was *not* broken out of:

```
def cipher_attack(partial_alphabetic, ciphertext):
    var = ""
    for letter in ciphertext:
        for i, pa in enumerate(partial_alphabetic):
            if pa == letter:
                var += alphabet[i % 26]
                break
        else:
            var += "!"                    
    return var
```

Note that you can loop over `ciphertext` and `partial_alphabetic` **directly**, no need to create an index first. Having the index, however, helps match against `alphabet`, but creating the index in addition is easier with `enumerate()`.

Demo:

```
>>> import string
>>> alphabet = string.ascii_letters
>>> def cipher_attack(partial_alphabetic, ciphertext):
...     var = ""
...     for letter in ciphertext:
...         for i, pa in enumerate(partial_alphabetic):
...             if pa == letter:
...                 var += alphabet[i % 26]
...                 break
...         else:
...             var += "!"                    
...     return var
... 
>>> cipher_attack("!wertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm", "rqr")
'd!d'
```

Comment: Now I have to delete my answer :(

Comment: @thefourtheye: not if you find an angle to add that others missed or forgot about. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters it gives me this answer '!!!d!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!d'

Comment: @ranatamer: Look closely at the indentation of `else:`. It matches the `for` statement, **not** the `if` test!

Comment: You could use `str.find` instead of looping through the entire `partial_alphabetic`

Comment: @Ivo: That is what `.find()` and `.index()` do *too*, but in C code. To test membership (`in`) you also need to loop through the list. This *combines* both loops, and breaks out early. So, this does *one* loop instead of two, and when a match is found, ends the loop. The C versions still may be faster on lower performance costs, but asymptotically this is the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def cipher_attack(partial_alphabetic,ciphertext):
    var = ""
    for c in chipertext:
        if c in partial_alphabetic: var+=c
        else: var+='!'
    return var

cipher_attack("!wertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm","rqr")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use [str.translate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate):

```
import string
def cipher_attack(partial_alphabetic, ciphertext):
    missing = ''.join(set(ciphertext).difference(partial_alphabetic))
    table = string.maketrans(
        partial_alphabetic+missing,
        string.letters[:len(partial_alphabetic)]+'!'*len(missing))
    return (ciphertext.translate(table))

print(cipher_attack('!wertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm', 'rqr'))
```

prints

```
d!d
```

Typically, `str.translate` executes faster than equivalent code that loops through a string character-by-character. In your example, `ciphertext` is so short it hardly matters, but for longer texts it can be significant.

Using a looping solution as `cipher_attack2` for comparison:

```
In [43]: %timeit cipher_attack('!wertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm', 'rqr'*10000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 696 µs per loop

In [44]: %timeit cipher_attack2('!wertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm', 'rqr'*10000)
10 loops, best of 3: 32 ms per loop

In [45]: 32000/696.
Out[45]: 45.97701149425287
```